# TypeError when reading CBOR file

Tags: python, json, cbor

I am working on a project using the CBOR file to contain data. I already install `cbor` with `pip install cbor`. But I cannot read it.

This is my code:

```
import cbor
cbor.loads(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\project\score.cbor")
```

Then its return this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\pyenv\lib\site-packages\cbor\cbor.py", line 263, in loads
    fp = StringIO(data)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

How to solve this problem? And is there a way to convert CBOR to JSON file because I find it easier to work with the JSON file in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still don't know how to solve this problem with `cbor`, I use `cbor2` instead and it works.

```
import cbor2
path = "home/data/score.cbor"

with open(path, 'rb') as fp:
    obj = cbor2.load(fp)
    print(obj)
```

Output

```
{'root': {'probe': 20, 'candidate': 31}, 'tree': [], 'support': []}
```

Comment: I've been working on a command line tool for cbor2 which dumps it's output to json: https://github.com/agronholm/cbor2/pull/72 There is also the remarshal project: https://github.com/dbohdan/remarshal which aims to convert many different serialization formats.